# NSMutableArray - Add array at start

Tags: ios, ios7, nsmutablearray, append

It is a simple pull to refresh case. I have data loaded into table and have a mutable data array at back-end, I receive a array of new data and want to add this complete array at start of existing array.

One workaround is to create new array with new arrived data and then add previous array into it using  `addObjectsFromArray:` method. Is there some workaround to add new data array to the start of previous array directly?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

First, build an `NSIndexSet`.

```
NSIndexSet *indexes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:
    NSMakeRange(0,[newArray count])];
```

Now, make use of `NSMutableArray`'s `insertObjects:atIndexes:`.

```
[oldArray insertObjects:newArray atIndexes:indexes];
```

---

Alternatively, there's this approach:

```
oldArray = [[newArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:oldArray] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: The alternative solution is the simplest solution for me. (y)

Answer (score 2):

`NSMutableArray` offers the `insertObjects:atIndexes:` method, but it's easier to append the way you suggest using `addObjectsFromArray:`.

Answer (score 1):

`-insertObject:atIndexes:` is easy enough, and should (I believe) be more efficient than using `-addObjects` and swapping arrays. It'd probably end up looking something like this:

```
[existingResults addObjects:newResults atIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, newResults.count)]]`
```

Comment: Simple and nice:) I believe newResults.count should be newResults.count-1.

Comment: I don't think so; the second argument to NSMakeRange() is the count, not the ending index. But thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new array is probably your best solution, but you can also use a loop

```
NSUInteger index;

index = 0;
for ( id item in sourceArray )
{
    [destArray insertObject:item atIndex:index];
    index++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simple way:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayTmp = [firstArr addObjectsFromArray:myArray];
myArray = arrayTmp;
```