# addObjectsFromArray to the beginning of an existing array

Tags: arrays, swift, nsmutablearray

I'm having trouble adding an existing array to the beginning of another array.
For example:
 MutableID array contains 1,2,3,4,5 & idArray array contains 6,7,8

```
self.MutableID.addObjectsFromArray(idArray as [AnyObject])
//currently puts values to the end of the array not the beginning
```

this code outputs 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 but I want it to output 6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5

I need the values added to the beginning of self.MutableID Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22492787/2792531

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSMutableArray - Add array at start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492706/nsmutablearray-add-array-at-start)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSMutableArray has insertObjects method.

```
self.MutableID.insertObjects(otherArray as [AnyObject], atIndexes: NSIndexSet(indexesInRange: NSMakeRange(0, otherArray.count)))
```

Or you can assign the mutable array to a swift array and use insertContentsOf method ;)

```
self.MutableID = NSMutableArray(array: [1,2,3,4])
var otherArray = NSMutableArray(array: [6,7,8,9])

var swiftArr : [AnyObject] = self.MutableID as [AnyObject]
swiftArr.insertContentsOf(otherArray as [AnyObject], at: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.MutableID.insertContentsOf(idArray as [AnyObject], at: 0)
```

Comment: NSMutableArray has no member insertConsentsOf

Comment: When you use Swift you shouldn't use `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` directly. Use `var MutableID: [Int]` instead.

Comment: You can't add objects from a `[AnyObject]` to a `[Int]`.

Comment: @SlopTonio If you *need* to use `NSMutableArray`, your question should make that clear with more than just the tags.

Comment: @nhgrif No need to cast `idArray` to `[AnyObject]` then. Or just use `var MutableID: [AnyObject]` if really necessary.

Comment: I'm new to swift, why is it not recommended to use NSMutableArray directly?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

This question is the Swift version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22492787/2792531) which solves the problem in Objective-C.

If we *must*, for whatever reason, be using Objective-C's `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`, then we can simply use a Swift translation of the code in my answer over there:

```
let range = NSMakeRange(0, newArray.count)
let indexes = NSIndexSet(indexesInRange: range)
oldArray.insertObjects(newArray as [AnyObject], atIndexes: indexes)
```

Where `oldArray` is an `NSMutableArray` and `newArray` is `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`.

Or the other approach, append and reassign:

```
oldArray = newArray.arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray(oldArray as [AnyObject])
```

---

But the most correct thing to do would be to use the Swift Array type, and then use the `insertContentsOf(_: Array, at: Int)` method, as [fluidsonic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34202978/2792531) describes.